# How to design textbox (<input>) in firefox and chrome look same?

Tags: html, css

below is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
input {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
</style>
<input name="page_search" placeholder="Quick search..." type="text">
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

in firefox look like below

[image: firefox]

in chrome its like below

[image: chrome]

but the input (i think its '`padding`') is look different in firefox and cromo why?

Comment: just increase the height. http://jsfiddle.net/nWgBC/

Comment: yes, i try like that but there is height difference in these two

Comment: Declare `font-size`, `font-family` and `line-height` properties **explicitly**.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the Height it will take automatically depends upon your text length and width

Comment: ...and it will be different depending on the browser, so that's the opposite of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to play with styles a bit. Also consider using a CSS Reset file which resets all the default style settings in the browsers.

I tried the following css and it looks close enough in both Firefox and Chrome:

```
input {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    color: gray;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5nbu6/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just change padding to auto.

check the solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jrkGE/)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
input {
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    color: gray;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:15px;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/5nbu6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `font-size: 10px;` too. 
Each of these browsers has other default input text font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS resets to remove all browser default styles and reduce browser inconsistencies. Popular ones include: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ for HTML5.

Answer (score -1):

Code looks good, Try Adding this supporting tag for chrome

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```